# Failed to execute goal & Hibernate invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: hibernate, maven, build

i try to build my Project with maven (goal: package clean) but i get the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project minimalistic-mvc-example: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/chris/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.9.Final/hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Seems like your local jar file is corrupted. 
Delete your local Maven repo and try again. 
This will force maven to download the jar again, from remote repo.

In windows by default local maven repo will be in `C:\Users\username\.m2\repository`

Comment: Deleting didn't solve the problem.  mvn downloaded the .jar file again and gave the same error.

Comment: instead of deleting the entire maven directory you can just delete the problem dependency and call a maven update to re-download it.  this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check your .jar file may be corrupted so delete from your repository  and try again to restart server so it can get again new one hop so it will helpful

Answer (score 0):

Delete contents from `C:\Users\Username\.m2\repository`. Either everything
or selectively - your choice.
Then use the command prompt to force download jars and build

```
mvn clean install
```

after run test:

```
mvn test
```